# MongoDB Connection Error in Go: Target Machine actively refusing connection. Code from Mongo website used

Tags: database, mongodb, go

I am working on connecting to the Facebook API using MongoDB.

I am receiving an error that states: ***"server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp [::1]:27017: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. }, ] }"***

In attempts to fix this error, I have tried switching to servers "mongodb://localhost:27018" and "mongodb://localhost:27019"

I have also scanned my code for errors but can't find anything. I am still very new to programming, so any help or additional advice/ knowledge is appreciated.

Code Below:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "log"
)

// Client is exported Mongo Database client
var Client *mongo.Client

// ConnectDatabase is used to connect the MongoDB database
func ConnectDatabase() {
    log.Println("Database connecting...")
    // Set client options
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client,err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
    Client = client
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Check the connection
    err = Client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("Database Connected.")
}
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database from any other tool (like Compass or mongo shell) using this uri string: "mongodb://localhost:27017"

Comment: To be honest, I do not know how to check that. This is my first time connecting to a database. Do I need to download Compass / mongo shell to do that? Or could I do a go get in the terminal to get those

Comment: Compass to be downloaded. _Depending upon your database version_ shell (`mongosh` or `mongo` shell) may be included or to be downloaded as part of tools. Refer the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: Try using the _context_ from this post: [Golang & MongoDB QuickStart](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup)''s Getting Started. Better, try the example. By default, a client connects to MongoDB on 'localhost' and 27017 port. Make sure your db is up and running before you connect from a client program like `mongo` shell, Compass, or a Golang program.

Comment: Thank you for this advice!! I downloaded Compass and tried the example after creating my own Atlas cluster. I was able to properly connect to my Atlas cluster and print out the databases from my cluster. So the example code worked! However I tried using the same code to connect to the mongoDB URI by swapping my Atlas URI for mongodb://localhost:27017 and it gave the same 'actively refused' error as before when I wrote this post. 

So that must mean something is wrong with the mongodb://localhost:27017 link with either mongoDB or the 27017 port..? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: I found the answer! It's ridiculous. I hadn't downloaded Mongo DB and installed it as a service! LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the incredibly simple answer. I hadn't downloaded the MongoDB community server and installed it as a service!

After installing I ran my code with http://localhost:8000/ and it worked immediately.

Link here: https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community